# Bootstrap navbar brand (name) not showing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

On this [test page](http://andrewsamonas.com/test.html) I am using Bootstrap. I don't see the brand name showing. What am I doing wrong? in case you need these links, here is http://andrewsamonas.com/css/bootstrap.min.css
here is http://andrewsamonas.com/css/custom2.css
relevant navbar code

```html
<div class="row main-navigation-container navbar-fixed-top" id="primary-navbar">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Mobile Toggle Button and stuff -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="" target="_blank" title="Atlantic Four Winds"> Atlantic Four Winds</a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End of mobile toggle button -->
                    <!-- Start of the navbar -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-navigation">
                        <ul class="nav  nav-justified">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="rates.html">Rates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
                             <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">Things To Do <b class="caret"></b></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li><a href="http://ryebeachinfo.com/" target="_blank">Rye Beach</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="https://www.nhstateparks.org/visit/state-parks/jenness-state-beach.aspx" target="_blank">Jenness State Beach</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="http://www.nhstateparks.com/wallis.html" target="_blank">Wallis Sands Beach</a></li>
                           <li><a href="http://www.newcastlenh.org/pages/newcastlenh_common/great" target="_blank">Great Island Commons</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="http://www.nhstateparks.org/visit/state-parks/odiorne-point-state-park.aspx" target="_blank">Odiorn State Park</a></li>
                           <li><a href="http://www.nhstateparks.org/visit/state-parks/rye-harbor-state-park.aspx" target="_blank">Rye Harbor State Park</a></li>  
                           <li><a href="http://www.seacoastsciencecenter.org/" target="_blank">Seacoast Science Center</a></li>
                           <li><a href="http://www.granitestatewhalewatch.com/" target="_blank">Granite State Whale Watch</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="http://www.atlanticwhalewatch.com/" target="_blank">Atlantic Whale Watch</a></li> 
                           <li><a href="http://www.portsmouthharbor.com/" target="_blank">Portsmouth Harbor Cruises</a></li> 
                          <li><a href="http://ryeairfield.com/" target="_blank">Rye Airfield</a></li>
                           </ul>
                           </li>
                            <li><a href="map.html">Map</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom css file you're setting `a.navbar-brand:visited` to `display: none`